# Why is Image.composite returning a "bad mask" error when I used one of the 2 images as a mask?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=seK1Lrlv81Y) and the guy used the one of the 2 images as the mask. But for me it's not working. Why is this?

```
from PIL import Image

img1 = Image.open("beach.jpg")
img2 = Image.open("joker.jpg")

maxsize = min(img1.size,img2.size)

newratio = min(maxsize[0]/img2.size[0],maxsize[1]/img1.size[1])

newimg1width = int(img1.size[0]*newratio)
newimg1height = int(img1.size[1]*newratio)

newimgtuple = (newimg1width,newimg1height)

newimg = img1.resize(newimgtuple)

compimg = Image.composite(newimg, img2, newimg)

compimg.save("compimg.jpg")
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dude\Desktop\Desktop\Projects\Youtube\Wordtoon\test.py", line 44, in <module>
    compimg = Image.composite(newimg, img2, newimg)
  File "C:\Users\dude\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2376, in composite
    image.paste(image1, None, mask)
  File "C:\Users\dude\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1344, in paste
    self.im.paste(im, box, mask.im)

ValueError: bad transparency mask
```

Comment: what tutorial ? you didn't add url to tutorial. Check PIL documentation - maybe you use wrong arguments or images have wrong sizes: http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.4.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.composite

Comment: @furas added the link.

Comment: @furas what does it mean by "must have the same mode"?

Comment: as in description: `mask – A mask image. This image can have mode “1”, “L”, or “RGBA”`. Mode means that both images have to be `RGB` or `greyscale`, etc.

Comment: first use `print()` to check all variables with sizes. You can create images with different sizes.

Comment: Ok so I converted the mask to `RGBA`. This got rid of the error. But the function doesn't seem to do anything. It just spits out one of the 2 images right back at me.